# What is the best way to convert BLOB hex string to JPG in java?

Tags: java, blob, javax.imageio

I'm trying to convert a hex representation of a .jpg stored in database as BLOB back to an image. In the following snippet I'm reading in the hex from the image.txt file which contains the hex string: 0xFFD8FFE000104A4649460001010100C800C80000FF...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("image.txt"));
    String imageString = new String(encoded).trim();

    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(hexStringToByteArray(imageString));
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bis);

    File outputFile = new File("output.jpg");
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputFile);
}

public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String str) {
    String hexStr = str.substring(2);
    byte[] buf = new byte[hexStr.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < hexStr.length(); i += 2) {
        if (i != hexStr.length() - 1) {
            buf[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(str.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(str.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
    }

    return buf;
}
```

For me the ImageIO.read is not working. It always returns null and therefore an IllegalArgumentException is thrown by ImageIO.write, because image must not be null.

Can anyone help or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: If these bytes are always representing a JPEG image, then there is no reason to use ImageIO at all. You should only convert the hex string to bytes and write these directly to disc. And for reading the text file you should use a Reader, because it is text. It looks very strange what you do with readAllBytes() for a text file.

Comment: Thanks for the support. Tt's been a while since i last worked with Java